# Android Camera in portrait error for Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-galaxy

How to keep camera in portrait mode in all devices?
my app is above 2.2

I tried

[image]

```
public void setRotation(int rotation) {

    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        degrees = 0;
        break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        degrees = 90;
        break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        degrees = 180;
        break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        degrees = 270;
        break;
    }

    int result;

    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);

    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (cameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    } else { // back-facing
        result = (cameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }

    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

but samsung devices ignoring `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90)`

**Edited:**

devices I found ignoring this:

Galaxy y(GT-S5360)(Android 2.3.6)

Galaxy Ace(GT-S5830)(Android 2.6.3)

but Galaxy S2 and other higher phones working well.

Comment: what samsung devices are ignoring the setDisplayOrientation?

Comment: Hi. Did you managed to find a solution for this issue ? I have the same issue on a Galaxy Ace device.

Comment: Have you checked this https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/solving-image-rotation-on-android-using-camera2-api-7b3ed3518ab6

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    public int getCorrectCameraOrientation(CameraInfo info, Camera camera) {

  int rotation = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
  int degrees = 0;

  switch(rotation){
     case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        degrees = 0;
        break;

     case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        degrees = 90;
        break;

     case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        degrees = 180;
        break;

     case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        degrees = 270;
        break;

  }

  int result;
  if(info.facing==Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
    result = (360 – result) % 360;  
  }else{
    result = (info.orientation – degrees + 360) % 360;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Use this method as

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(getCorrectCameraOrientation(mCameraInfo, mCamera));
```

This is not enough for rotation handling, you need to do below step also

```
mCamera.getParameters().setRotation(getCorrectCameraOrientation(mCameraInfo, mCamera));
```